# How to prevent Visual Studio on breaking on exception which seems to be handled in Python internally?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

I want to debug my **Python** application with **Visual Studio 2022 Pro** and am just configuring the solution. I've stumbled upon a very persistant exception, which breaks execution every time I debug my application and it is annoying that I have to **continue** several times before the application actually runs.

The minimum sample to preproduce the issue looks like this:

```
import enum
class MyParentClass(enum.Enum):
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        return super().__getattribute__(item)

class MyEnum(MyParentClass):
    OPTION1 = 1
    OPTION2 = 2
    OPTION3 = 3
```

What happens is that `return super().__getattribute__(item)`  throws `AttributeError` exception several times. This seems all to be part of some **internal Python logic**. I got to the point just before the exception and it looks like this exception is triggered in `enum.py`, specifically `__new__` function, which calls `hasattr(enum_member, '_value_')`.

I couldn't go deeper with the debugger, as it seems this part is not implemented in Python. But considering how the code executes normally afterwards, as if the exception wasn't thrown at all, I'm guessing there is some internal code, which handles this exception.

The main problem seems to be that Visual Studio seems to think this is an unhandled exception and breaks there unconditionally. I tried disabling all exceptions, so it wouldn't break on any, but what I see is that it breaks only on unhandled exceptions. So I'm guessing this is the gist of the problem. I also tried toggling the option **Enable Just My Code**, but it made no difference in this case.

When I try to debug the same code with **PyCharm**, it works alright, it doesn't break on this exception by default.

So my question is - how can I make Visual Studio ignore such exceptions?